# Refer to a key in map to add content. React native

Tags: react-native

I am doing an app that gets information about a sports game from a provider. They provide goals and assists in two different objects, looks something like this:

```
incidents: {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    type: 'goal'
  },
  2: {
    id: 2
    type: 'assist'
    referto: 1
 }
```

As you can see in the object above, the object with id 2 is an assist which refers to object with id 1.

So I want to map this object and return a `<View>` with the data, and if type = assist, I want it to append to the View which the id refers to.

Below is a mix of jQuery and React, but I hope you understand.

```
Object.map(incident => {
   if (incident.type === 'assist') {
     incident.referto.append( //refer to the View with key = incident.referto
       <View><Text>I am an assist to the goal above</Text></View>
     );
   }
)};
```

How can I do something like this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
I want to add "assist" view component inside the "goal" view component. I hope that will make it a bit clearer, sorry.

Comment: This is a bit hard to solve. Don't add code jQuery-like code if you want to do it with RN. So, you'd like to add "assist" View component inside the "goal" View component? Please, rephrase your question to get proper answers.

Comment: I just wrote some jQuery-like so maybe someone would understand. But yes, adding "assist" View component inside the "goal" View component. 
You described it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Best way of going at it is to use a conditional render.

```
{
  incident.type === 'assist' &&
  <View>
    <Text>I am an assist to the goal above</Text>
  </View>
}
```

By doing so you add the views only when incident type is assist, otherwise they are non-existent.

While not advised, another way of going at it would be to abuse `React.createElement(component, props, ...children)`. However, such a solution is likely not what you want, and probably what you wish to achieve can be achieved using JSX.